# Optimizely Tool change colors for multiply buttons

Tags: html, css

There is a tool called as "Optimizely Tool" using for html and css changes. I need change colors of some multiply buttons and also in another website i have to change some sublinks color again.

Is there anyone using this tool and can help me about that? Normally i know HTML very well, and css weak. But this tool confusing me hard..

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: uhm ok then i shall delete my question. Is there any way to do it? Or just push delete button?